# Select item from a Combo React JS application

Tags: karate

I was using below code to select an item from a list box using selenium, since select was not available .. How can I achieve the same in Karate.

public void selectOption(WebDriver driver, List ele, String option) throws InterruptedException {
for(WebElement i: ele){

```
        if (i.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(option)){
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(i);
            actions.click().perform();
            break;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#select

Something like this:

```
* select('select[name=data1]', '{}Option Visible Text')
```

If you are still stuck, please follow this process so that we can fix anything if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test